# How to define a literal type base on input params

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to make an `createContext` than include a name prefix for returned object, how can tell the user that the return value keys is based on input params, I tried

```
export function createContext<Name extends string = string>(
  name: Name,
): {
  [`use${name}Context`]: any;
  [`${name}Provider`]: any;
};

export function createContext(name:string){
    return {
        [`use${name}Context`]:0,
        [`${name}Provider`]:0
    }
}
```

But I don't understand the error

```
A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.(1170)
```

Dose that mean this is impossible ?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzVYAQxmAGEcSQYAeAOUIFtg5QSUATAZzk5ikxQBzOAF4efAYIB8ACgBQcOCkbAAXHHpMANHICU6gN4K4AbQAGSTsAAkB5UwC+5FJRhmAuusIoAngG5jc1t7YAcABSgIADdMdmAoDy9fAIcAuVBIWERUDGxcfCISZ1cZENVefiFdI0VFAhgkKFwa2tbzSxs7FScKVkSABh1WtrNg7ojo2PiB40UHOXmgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html). Also don't forget to use the uppercase generic type `Name` instead of `name`.

```
export function createContext<Name extends string = string>(
  name: Name,
): {
  [K in `use${Name}Context` | `${Name}Provider`]: any;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzVYAQxmAGEcSQYAeAOUIFtg5QSUATAZzk5ikxQBzOAF4efAYIB8ACgBQcOCkbAAXHHpMANHICU6gN4K4AbQDScAXAAGSTsAAkBzcAC%205FJRjW4AHxtOLq4AClAQAG6Y7MBQ1gC66oQoAJ4A3HKu6XKgkLCIqBjYuPhEJB5eMspMqrz8QrpGiooEMEhQuI1NXSa29k5VbuWs8aoADDpd3db9KiFhkdGxCaPGiq4ZckA)

---

If you want both properties to have different types, you can intersect multiple mapped types.

```
export function createContext<Name extends string = string>(
  name: Name,
): {
  [K in `use${Name}Context`]: number;
} & {
  [K in `${Name}Provider`]: string
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzVYAQxmAGEcSQYAeAOUIFtg5QSUATAZzk5ikxQBzOAF4efAYIB8ACgBQcOCkbAAXHHpMANHICU6gN4K4AbQDScAXAAGSTsAAkBzcAC+5FJRjWAuupRIDABGwFAA3HKucABkcEaK5pa41k4urgAKUBAAbpjsob7qvPxCkRFyoJCwiKgY2Lj4RCQeXjLKTKrFkrrxinAEMEhQuL19fSa29k7tbi2shXAADDpjYxPTKhlZuflQCwBEhEFo+8aKrpFycmg4vP3AnEgANvBijcRkFKwyh8f7unIAPSAsYAPQA-EA)